# Why am I getting deadlock when using semaphores in recursive functions calls

Tags: multithreading, swift

Why am I getting deadlock when using semaphores in recursive functions calls?

I need to do several synchronous HTTP GET requests so I wrote the following function:

```
func doSynchronousHTTPGetRequest(url: String, completionHandler: (NSData!, NSURLResponse!, NSError!) -> Void) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: url) {
        let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {
            (data, response, error) in

            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);

            completionHandler(data, response, error)
        }
        task.resume()

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }
}
```

And when I call it like this:

```
    self.doSynchronousHTTPGetRequest("https://2ch.hk/b/threads.json") {
        (data, response, error) in

        self.doSynchronousHTTPGetRequest("https://2ch.hk/b/threads.json") {
            (data, response, error) in
            // ...
        }
    }
```

It waits indefinitely on the second waiting.

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: You mean that it freezes after the 2nd call, or it never reaches that point?

Comment: @Antonio It waits indefinitely on the second dispatch_semaphore_wait function call. Also, I just noticed that breakpoint on the dispatch_semaphore_create function call triggered 3 times

Comment: Never used semaphores in iOS - however I notice that you are not releasing it once used - shouldn't you call `dispatch_release` after wait?

Comment: Also not sure if the problem is about what is done *next*, after the 1st `doSynchronousHTTPGetRequest` is completed, which happens on the 1st `dispatch_semaphore_signal` call. Can you post the code after the 2 nested calls?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it hangs but the fix would be:

```
func doSynchronousHTTPGetRequest(url: String, completionHandler: (NSData!, NSURLResponse!, NSError!) -> Void) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: url) {
        let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        var _data:NSData!
        var _response:NSURLResponse!
        var _error:NSError!

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
            // set the results to outer variables
            (_data, _response, _error) = (data, response, error)

            // then restart the main thread
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        }
        task.resume()

        // Here is always main thread
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); // wait until signalled...
        // Main thread restarted!
        // call callback closure from main thread.
        completionHandler(_data, _response, _error)
    }
}

doSynchronousHTTPGetRequest("https://2ch.hk/b/threads.json") {
    (data, response, error) in
    doSynchronousHTTPGetRequest("https://2ch.hk/b/threads.json") {
        (data, response, error) in
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

The main difference is in which thread `completionHandler` will be called.

With my code, it's the main thread, but with the OP code, it's another thread.

---

I think, I found the reason:

```
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in

        // print current queue's concurrent count
        println(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()?.maxConcurrentOperationCount)

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        completionHandler(data, response, error)
    }
```

This prints `1`, means it's **serial queue**. It seems, `NSURLSession` uses one serial queue for multiple requests.

Then at the second call, in that serial queue,

1. create semaphore.
2. create and `resume()` the task.
3. lock the thread with `dispatch_semaphore_wait` until the semaphore signalled.

This causes **dead lock**. that's why OP code hangs.

Comment: Could you outline what the differences are?

Comment: >NSURLSession uses one serial queue for multiple requests.
indeed it does uses serial queue by default.